# How do I use newline characters in an interpolated string with newlines?

Tags: javascript, graphql-js

I am having issues adding newline characters into a string that already has newlines.

For example:

```
const foo = "test\ntest";
const string = `mutation {
   some_field: "${foo}"
}`;
```

This will be output as:

```
mutation {
   some_field: "test
test"
}
```

But I want it to output as:

```
mutation {
   some_field: "test\ntest"
}
```

Where the existing white-space/newlines are preserved but you can add a string like `"test\ntest"` inside of it. This current line-breaking is causing syntax errors.

I have tried adding together these strings in various different ways but I can't figure out how to force `\n` to remain `\n` in the field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have \n in a JavaScript string literal, it represents a newline character, not a backslash followed by n. If you want a backslash followed by n, you have to escape the backslash character with another backslash character. That is, you have to put \n in the string literal.

```js
const foo = "test\\ntest";
const string = `mutation {
   some_field: "${foo}"
}`;

console.log(string)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was trying to do this but my regex was wrong. This finally fixed it for reference `foo.replace(/\n/g, '\\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put literal `\n` in the string by escaping the backslash.

```js
const foo = "test\\ntest";
const string = `mutation {
   some_field: "${foo}"
}`;

console.log(string);
```

But this seems like it's fraught with danger. You should almost certainly be using JSON, not a template literal.

```js
const foo = "test\ntest";
const string = `mutation ${JSON.stringify({
   some_field: foo
}, null, 4)}`;

console.log(string);
```